# Getting 'InternalServiceFault' exception when trying to invoke a svc webservice(hosted in IIS server)

Tags: android, .net

Getting 'InternalServiceFault' exception when trying to invoke a svc webservice(hosted in IIS server) using ksoap2 in Android.

Exception happening :

> W/System.err﹕ SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:InternalServiceFault'
>   faultstring: 'OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body.
>   Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'GetUnits' and
>   namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name
>   'GetUnits' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/IRestaurant/''
>   faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@40c821a8 05-11
>   22:26:30.068      913-921/com.org.ansal.placemaorder W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:137)

Request :

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:itemId>1</tem:itemId>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Invocation code:

```
  new FetchData(LoginActivity.this).execute("http://tempuri.org/IRestaurant/","GetUnits","http://10.0.0.2/RestaurantServices/RegistrationServices.svc");
```

Service call

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String result="";
    String _NAMESPACE   = params[0];
    String _METHOD_NAME = params[1];
    String URL     = params[2];
    String _SOAP_ACTION = _NAMESPACE + _METHOD_NAME;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(_NAMESPACE, _METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("itemId",1);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\"?>");
        androidHttpTransport.call(_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject   resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        result  = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
        System.out.println("****** RESULT: " + resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("******* THERE WAS AN ERROR ACCESSING THE WEB SERVICE");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you have mismatched smth. What is your `_NAMESPACE` equal to?

Comment: "http://tempuri.org/IRestaurant/" this is the namespace. We are passing this as the firstparameter to the service calling function.                         new FetchData(LoginActivity.this).execute("http://tempuri.org/IRestaurant/","GetUnits","http://10.0.0.2/RestaurantServices/RegistrationServices.svc");

Comment: Change it to `tempuri.org` and try it, if any change?

Comment: Yes, I changed the namespace to "http://tempuri.org/" and it resolved the 'InternalServiceFault' exception. Then I was getting socket timeout exception which I resolved it by giving a timeout interval in the HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);

Comment: Well thats another `exception`, i answered what you have asked for only

Answer (score 1):

> Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'GetUnits' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'GetUnits' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/IRestaurant/''

Change your `Namespace` from:

```
"tempuri.org/IRestaurant/";
```

to:

```
"tempuri.org/"
```